# Custom define variables inside Apollo React Mutation Component

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo, graphql-js

My backend handles a AddLike mutation. That takes a UserId and a CommentId or PitchId. Depending on which you want to like. I would like to reuse my LikeButton component throughout the applikation In that way i need to define my variables inside my Apollo React Mutation to either take a CommentId or PitchID. Right now i can't seem to make anything work. Any suggestions? :-)

Heres the code for the component. The API GrahQL works. So nothing to change there.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Mutation } from 'react-apollo';
import { ADD_LIKE } from '../../GraphQLStatements/GraphQLStatements'; 

interface ILikeButtonProps {
currentUser : number;
type : any;
index: number;
}

const LikeButton: React.SFC<ILikeButtonProps> = (props) => {
let inputType : string = "pitchId"

const DefineType = () => {
    if (props.type === "comment") {
        inputType = "commentId"
    }
    else {
        inputType = "pitchId"
    }
}

return (
    <Mutation mutation={ADD_LIKE}>
        {(addLike) => (
            <i className="far fa-thumbs-up icon like__button"
                onClick={e => {
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();
                DefineType()
                addLike({ variables : { like : 
                    { "userId": props.currentUser,
                       inputType : props.index}
                    } 
                }).then ((res : any) => {
                    console.log(res.data.addLike.statusMessage)
                });
            }}>
            </i>
        )}
    </Mutation>
 );
};

export default LikeButton;
```

Right now this isn't working. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Adding square brackets around inputType worked:

```
addLike({ variables : { like : 
          { "userId": props.userId,
            [inputType]: props.id}
          }
```